# How to turn off the Toggle Keys indicator on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, capslock, numlock, scroll-lock

Ever since I've updated to Windows 10 version 20H2, my PCs have been getting this weird pop-up whenever I pressed the caps lock key, the scroll lock key or the num lock key.

[image]

I've decided to open a new thread because the last thread on superuser claimed this was an OEM feature, but it's happening on 3 totally different PCs; an ASUS laptop, an ASUS desktop, and a Samsung tablet PC. The exact same pop-up, font and design and colour and all. I use the Samsung tablet PC in touchscreen mode and when I'm typing, the pop-up covers my on-screen keyboard, so I'd like to get rid of it. The Windows 10 Settings app has no setting to turn these off, or I'm not looking in the correct places for it.

I've thought it could be a feature of Razer Synapse, Logitech's G HUB, or AMD's Radeon software, maybe Nvidia's control panel, but my Samsung tablet PC has neither of those installed, my desktop PC doesn't have G HUB nor Radeon software installed, and my laptop has all 4 of those.

If anyone knows where this pop-up comes from, what app causes it, or if it's a Windows 10 feature, where to turn it off, I'd be extremely thankful for any help.

Comment: None of my PC's with Windows 10 version 20H2 have this behavior, various brands also. I suggest a clean install of W10, I bet the problem will be gone.

Comment: Look for a friendly keyboard product that you have installed on all three computers.

Comment: I reset my Samsung tablet fully and sadly it persisted, but thanks to @harrymc and the other answer I've received, I managed to figure out it might be something to do with my Logitech bluetooth keyboard I used temporarily during the setup of touchscreen drivers, even though I've installed no software for it on the Samsung tablet. Thank you very much for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicator is from Logitech SetPoint software.  To disable it, open Logitech SetPoint.  Go to the Tools tab at top.  Then the SetPoint Options tab on the side.  Then you will see the Status Indicators section on the right, where you can enable/disable the notification.

Comment: Sadly, I don't use SetPoint, but I assume this display is shared between all Logitech apps, even G HUB. I tried looking in the settings but nothing let me turn them off, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Mine was the Logitech Options app. In the app go to any of your keyboard > More > Notifications > Caps Lock

Unchecked that checkbox and the indicator is gone!

Answer (score 0):

**In the event you have Logitech Options installed but can't find the settings screen other answers talk about:**

From my experience this is most commonly caused by either Logitech's `SetPoint` software or `LogitechOptions` software (different software for different models of peripherals).

While I'm not sure about `SetPoint`, for `LogitechOptions` there is apparently a bug where the CAPSLOCK notification can get toggled and then stay on. This usually happens if you plug in a logitech keyboard as the software defaults to having that option on.

Normally you can go into the keyboard options and disable the pop-up, however if you no longer have the keyboard plugged in then the software just doesn't give you the menu to disable the option.

The easiest way I've found to quickly fix this is by modifying the settings file directly:

1. On `Windows`, navigate to your local app data - WIN+R  --> `%appdata%\Logishrd\LogiOptions`
2. Find **options.xml** and open in a text editor of some sorts
3. Find and modify the line `<useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />` to have `value=0` to disable the notification
4. Restart / open `LogitechOptions` software to let changes take effect
5. Regain sanity